# OnTouchEvent for RecylerView AND its items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Briefly to say, I have a `RecyclerView` (a ViewGroup) which should response to `TouchEvent`, while I also suppose that its item can response individually to TouchEvent.

However, that seems to be impossible for me. For example, if I make both in `onTouchEvent()` method, then if the item(child view) return a true when `ACTION_DOWN`, then `ViewGroup` cannot catch it, whereas if `false`, the child self cannot response to `ACTION_MOVE` or `ACTION_UP`.

I also turned to `addOnItemTouchListener()` `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, but none works.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear. But based on my understanding, you want to get the click event for entire view and also for each item at the same time.

Get click event for entire view

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            // this will be called multiple times for single click - for MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, and MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
            // So restricting the call only for ACTION_DOWN,
            if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked view", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {}
    });
```

and to get the click event for each item, add click listener in onBindViewHolder function

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked Item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are right, but there is a little problem fot me because I wanna get TouchEvent for both the entire view and correspondent item, not just onClick because something I need to do when ACTION_DOWN or move or up

Answer (score 0):

Instead of touch listener you can also use click listener on any element of recycler view row...